# Keras load sound instances in batches

Tags: python, keras

I need help trying to figure out how to achieve batch loading with Keras.

So far I'm trying to make a song classifier with Keras CNN. I've built the model below for 10 genre classification.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(16, 5, padding="same", input_shape=(1, 661500)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, padding="same"))

model.add(Conv1D(16, 5, padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, padding="same"))

model.add(Conv1D(16, 5, padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, padding="same"))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer="adam",
              loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

It's working when I load the instances and labels myself but my computer can't handle 1000 songs at once. I tried using ImageDataGenerator to load them in batches with flow_from_directory. The code is as below:

```
generator = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = generator.flow_from_directory("train",
                                                target_size=(1, 661500),
                                                batch_size=64,
                                                class_mode="categorical")
test_generator = generator.flow_from_directory("test",
                                               target_size=(1, 661500),
                                               batch_size=64,
                                               class_mode="categorical")

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=5584,
                    epochs=10,
                    validation_data=test_generator,
                    validation_steps=1861)
```

I ran into the problem of audio files not being images so I added .wav to whitelisted file formats in

```
\keras\Lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py
```

This let Keras to find the audio images but it can't really open them. I changed where it is opening them using Pillow to Librosa but it gives more errors. I don't think I can change all of them, so I was wondering if there's a way to achieve batch loading?

Edit: I came by to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47200146/keras-load-images-batch-wise-for-large-dataset) which pointed me to Keras [sequences](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) I implemented one as seen below.

```
class MySequence(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_files, y_files, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_files, y_files
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        from numpy import ceil
        return int(ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        from librosa import load
        from numpy import array, expand_dims
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

        return expand_dims(array([load(file_name)[0] for file_name in batch_x]), axis=1), array(batch_y)
```

This time the train times got ridiculously long. Previously, 10 epochs were completed in 3 hours but now it takes 14 hours for one epoch. Is there anything I can do to reduce train times?

Edit 2: Changed steps_per_epoch parameter in fit_generator function and it is down to acceptable levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like IO is the problem here. Maybe serialize your data in somthing like pickle and see if the training gets faster.

Step_per_epoch simply reduce the step in your epoch. So your training does not get faster you just don't use all your data in each epoch.

Comment: I assumed step_per_epoch should be sample_count / batch_size. When I train loading all of the data to RAM and using fit function, training progress is written as batch_size/sample_count [=========>....................]. Can you explain why it is different while using Sequence and normal training? How can I achieve normal training process using Sequences.

Comment: I never used steps_per_epoch, but with using Sequence the model function don't know the batchsize. It just receive the data from the Sequence so it can't tell wheter the first dimension is the bathc_size or something different. So it counts number of calls/Sequence.__len__(not 100% sure). The number besides the bar is different from using the normal fit function but this shouldn't make any difference in training.

Comment: From what I could understand step is how many times the Sequence.__getitem__ is called so batch_size * step_per_epoch = sample_count, as if I leave it to default, keras sets it to that value. Thank you for your help.