# How to load only batch data to in memory during training with estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, load, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

currently I train my model with estimator using below code. But when I use large dataset, my in memory (RAM) is not sufficient to load large dataset. So, is there a way to load only batch data to in memory while training with estimator?

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47200146/keras-load-images-batch-wise-for-large-dataset) example shown for keras. How can I implement it using estimator?

currently I am loading all my data in memory and feeding it to estimator.

```
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = convNet,model_dir='/dir')
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x": train_data},
        y=train_labels,
        batch_size=32,
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=True)
classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=657)
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use tf.data.dataset. such as : tf.data.TextLineDataset or tf.data.TFRecordDataset.

then process the batch_size, epoch,shuffle in input_fn:

```
    def input_fn():

        dataset=tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_path)

        dataset=dataset.map(map_fn)
        dataset=dataset.shuffle(shuffle).repeat(epochs).batch(batch_size)
        return dataset
```